# Array to store student's information

Tags: java, arrays

I need to do a array method to store student's information and calculate how many student's overall marks above or below average but I created in the main method. I need to put into class method therefore I don't know how to change it to class method and call it from main method.

```
int studentAbove =0;
int studentBelow=0;
String topLastName = "";
String belowLastName = "";
double totalOverall =0;
int studentCount=0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) != null) {
        double studentOverall = list.get(i).computeMarks();
        totalOverall = totalOverall +studentOverall;
        studentCount++;
    }
}

double averageOverall = totalOverall/studentCount;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) != null) {
        double studentOverall = list.get(i).computeMarks();
        if (studentOverall>=averageOverall){
            studentAbove++;
        }
        else studentBelow++;
    }
}

System.out.println(studentAbove + "scored above average overall");
System.out.println(studentBelow + "scored below average overall");
```

Comment: what does "I need to do a array method" mean?  You're trying to create a method that returns an array?

Comment: First, there is a distinct lack of arrays in this code block...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can extract method using refactor tool as follow:
select function code > right click > choose refactor > choose extract method (or simply after code selecting press Alt+Shift+M).This will give you static method.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no much details to can help you well.
But if us just need to be able to call your code block (method) within main method, i can think of two options:
1. like u saying above, u can wrap that code into a class method (make the method static), and call it with main.
2. u can make it an instance method
and within main, instantiate the class and the call the method
e.g:

```
public class DontKnowWhatThisIsAbout {
   public void showCalculations() { 
     //blah blah 
   } 
   public static void main(String args[]) { 
    new DontKnowWhatThisIsAbout().showCalculations(); 
   } 
}
```

It will be better to include why u doing what u doing, u may get better ideas.

Happy Coding.